# Basement Finishing Heat/AC

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, basement-refinishing, heat

So I have a 28ftx25ft basement wide open basement that i'm looking to frame and finish and need to make some choices on heat and cooling. For heat I have the extra BTUs on my furnace to run a second circulation pump and 2 lengths of cast iron baseboard off of it with a t-stat for the basement to operate things. I also have a sub panel with extra circuits that i can run and put in 2 lengths of electric baseboard.

Regarding AC, currently my split level is operating on a 1 zone. At some point i have to upgrade the unit in the attic and change the ductwork to be on a 2 zone system with 1 zone for the bedrooms and 1 zone for the common spaces.

Should I:

Do a mini split in the basement that does the heat and AC

Put no AC in the basement until i can afford to do the 2 zones, but run the ductwork in the basement now so that i can install the sheetrock for the ceiling.

Comment: What is the basement like now when using AC?  Cold air sinks, so quite a few basements stay cooler, when you are sweating upstairs.

Comment: I would not change the existing AC, but go for new one just for basement, it might run on completely different temperatures settings.